# How I can change the color of my ActionBar

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, android-actionbar

I'am using Android Studio 2.1.2 and want to change the color of my Action bar.
How I can do this? But with XML.
Please give me a detailed description to solve this problem

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

Comment: Color Name or hex-Code?

Comment: Put this inside ColorDrawable: Color.parseColor("#0000ff") or you can simply put this inside for example: 0xff00DDED

Comment: If that worked, please mark my answer as the answer. Thanks